# Como fechar um select ao clicar fora dele?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou construindo um select customizado com autocomplete e para isto estou usando algumas `<div>`'s, um `<input>` e jQuery.

Eu gostaria que ele tivesse o mesmo comportamento padrão de um select HTML de quando se clica fora do mesmo, ele se fecha.

Meu HTML, em linhas gerais, está assim:

```
<div class="my-select-container">
    <input id="my-input" type="text" value="" onkeyup="myAutocomplete(this);">
    <div class="my-options-container"></div>
</div>
```

Estou usando a função JavaScript `myAutocomplete()` para fazer todo trabalho de auto complete e manipular as divs com sucesso, meu único problema é fazer a div `my-options-container` se fechar ao clicar fora do select.

A função `myAutocomplete()` é a seguinte:

```
function autocomplete_region(obj) {
    var value = $(obj).val();

    // Only executes if there is some text on search input
    if (value) {
        // Mount request URL        
        var url = '/options/' + value + '/';

        // Send the request to server
        $.get(url,
            function (response) {
                // Continues only if there is a response
                var options = (response["options"] == undefined) ? response : response["options"];

                if (options.length > 0) {
                    // Clear old options
                    $('#my-options-container').html('');

                    // Populate items
                    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        var href_value = '/?code=' + options[i].code + '/';
                        var item = '<a id="option_' + i + '" href="' + href_value + '"><div>' + options[i].text + '</div></a>';

                        $('#my-options-container').html($('#my-options-container').html() + item);
                    }

                    // Shows options div
                    if ($('#my-options-container').is(':hidden'))
                        $('#my-options-container').show();

                } else {
                    $('#my-options-container').html('<span>Ops! Nenhuma opção disponível.</span>');

                    // Shows options div
                    $('#my-options-container').show();
                }
            });
    } else {
        // Hides options div
        $('#my-options-container').hide();

        // Empty options div
        $('#my-options-container').html('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara coloca o se script ai na pergunta tb, facilita para te responder e para similar a situação ai

Comment: Queres fechar o select quando o input perder o `focused` ou como o nativo quando clicares fora?

Comment: @Sergio Quando perder o `focused`seria melhor.

Comment: @hugocsl Achei desnecessário colocar a função `myAutocomplete()` na pergunta porque ela ficou relativamente grande por fazer outras coisas como pegar as opções em uma API além de apenas mostrar e esconder a `<div>` que mostra as opções.

Comment: Vc tá usando algum componente para criar o select ou está fazendo na mão mesmo?

Comment: @Sam Na mão mesmo.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a função (ou funções) e/ou o CSS que abre o select. Só assim dá pra saber como fazer o reverso (fechar o select).

Comment: Vou colocar então, um minuto.

Comment: Coloca aí que eu ajusto a minha resposta com mais exatidão.

Comment: @hugocsl Coloquei o script.

Comment: @Sam Veja se melhorou a pergunta.

Comment: Então. Vc vai colocar no `else` da minha resposta o mesmo `else` da função autocomplete. Esse `else` onde tem `// Hides options div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicar no `document` esvaziar e esconder a `div.#my-options-container`. Basta verificar no `click` no `document` se o local do click não é a `div.my-select-container`:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
   if($(e.target).closest(".my-select-container")[0]){
      e.stopPropagation();
   }else{
      $('#my-options-container').hide().empty();
   }
});
```

O `e.stopPropagation();` irá cancelar o click no `document` se o clique foi feito dentro da `div.my-select-container`.