# O que significa o trecho event.target === document.documentElement

Tags: javascript

No trecho de baixo do código "event.target === document.documentElement" o que exatamente isso faz?

(Esse script num todo faz com que se eu clico em um lugar fora menu mobile, ele fecha, mas esse trecho do script eu não entendi exatamente...)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significa se o elemento que disparou o evento `click` (`event.target`) foi o próprio documento (`document.documentElement`). Ou seja, se você clicar em qualquer lugar vazio na página onde não haja um elemento do `body` (div, a, input etc.), irá satisfazer a condição do `if`.

```
     operador de igualdade
       por valor e tipo
              ↑
event.target === document.documentElement
     ↓                   ↓
elemento que          <html>...</html>
disparou o evento
```

Agora, o mesmo poderia ser feito apenas com `document.onclick` em vez de `document.documentElement.onclick`. A diferença é que o `document` é um objeto que representa todo o documento, enquanto que `documentElement` é um objeto que representa a tag `html` da página.

Comment: Desta forma, se eu criar um modal (por exemplo) e clicar fora dele, essa condição irá ser válida para remover o modal? interessante

Comment: Não. Teria que usar outro código. Algo assim como nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/375537/8063